# Escape character for caret(^) in Powershell

Tags: regex, powershell, escaping

I need to replace `^~^` with a tab (`\t`) in a CSV file in PowerShell.
I tried escaping caret with a backtick (`` `^~`^ ``) but it doesn't work. How do I do this?

```
$file=Import-Csv $dataFilePath
$file -replace "\`^~\`^", "\`t"
```

Comment: As you are specifying a regular expression, I'd give \^ a try… inside the regex the escape character is a backslash, in powershell it's the backtick.

Comment: user the `[regex]::Escape()` method to add the needed escape chars for you. _much_ easier than doing it by hand ... [*grin*]

Answer (score 0):

Is that what you're looking for?

```
 >$s = "^~^"
 >$s -replace "\^\~\^", "``t"
 `t
```

Hope that helps.